# Undo option in Rich Content field

Tags: inputrichtext

My users are asking for an Undo option when editing a rich content field.  Is this possible?  My code currently is

```
          <lightning:inputRichText
               aura:id="jobsDetails"
               value="{!v.jobsDetails}"
               formats="['font', 'size', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline',
                         'strike', 'link', 'list', 'indent', 'align',
                         'clean', 'table', 'header', 'color']"
               valid="{!v.detailValid}"
               onblur="{!c.setSubmitButtonState}"
           />
```

Comment: could you please elaborate what an undo is usually shorts work (CLT +Z windows and cmd+z on mac) ??

Comment: Undo that my users want is the equivalent of Control-Z.  They have some applications in which there is a button that they can click to do undo what they hae just done.  What we really want is a rich content field icon that allows them to undo what they have just done.